# Textbox and label will not show up after the for loop ran

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make the textbox and label show up when the for loop is executed, however, both labels and textboxes don't show up. The sample code is down below.

```
 private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(hasInputed == true)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i <= numberofInput; i++)
                    {

                        numberofOrders = numberofInput - Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderNumberInput);

                       
                    }

                    lblFirstLast.Visible = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a numeric input, Limit amount of orders is 5");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please try again, Input Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you happens when you walk through this code?

Comment: So, the code runs clean and it doesn't show any errors, well syntax wise.

Comment: Put a debugger stop on the `try` line.  Run the code and when it hits the stop, tell the debugger to step into the next line (F11 key).  Use your mouse to hover over your variables to inspect their values.  "See" what is happening.

Comment: Okay, so it seems that the boolean is automatically going straight to the error even when there's an input number. Any tips on how to fix that? @LarsTech

Comment: This question is hard to follow. *I am trying to make the textbox and label show up when the for loop is executed* - the label will show whether the loop executes or not. No code here shows a textbox. *both labels and textboxes don't show up* - that could be true in the sense that the code shows a label but not a textbox? *the boolean is automatically going straight to the error* - presuming you're talking about `hasInputed == true` i'd love to know what exception that line of code throws

Comment: Trying to convert a textbox to an int with `Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderNumberInput)` won't work. It should probably read `Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderNumberInput.Text)`. Really puzzled why you didn't mention that a messagebox shows when you click the button.. is `numberofInput` negative?

Comment: Okay, I am trying your suggestion @CaiusJard. Also to further explain what I mean, the lblFirstLast is not visible, but I am wanting to make it appear once a numeric number has been inputed and the for loop has checked that the number is not more than 5. hope that makes sense

Comment: I wouldn't use a for loop to check if a number was more than 5. I could use `if(int.TryParse(txtThing.Text, out int thing) && thing is >0 and <=5)` but I'd actually probably use a NumericUpDown control, so that I didn't have to convert anything, i'd start it at 0 and ask the user to set it to something. A numeric updown can have a MaxValue of 5, so there isn't even anything to check; they simply cannot enter more than 5

Comment: @CaiusJard do you mind kindly typing an example?

Comment: An example of a NumericUpDown? It's hard to type because it's a GUI thing. Open your form designer, and in the toolbox where you found your textbox and label etc, find a NumericUpDown, drop it on the form and set its MinValue to 0, MaxValue to 5 and Value to 0. Give it a good name, and then you can just.. i dunno.. do `lblFirstLast.Visible = _nudWhatever.Value > 0` .. The label will appear if the user chooses anyhting other than 0

Comment: thank you, really appreciate it